# Sphinx- how to remove folder names/sub directories and file extensions from URL?

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I do my best to read and understand sphinx documentation but unfortunately I can't at this point :/. Also read many questions and answers on stackoverflow.

I want to remove all folder and sub folder names when a user clicks on a section on my page. How can I achieve this?

As an example I want to turn the URL's from these:

- http://127.0.0.1:5550/project/august/access-points.html
- http://127.0.0.1:5550/project/august/5G.html

To these:

- http://127.0.0.1:5550/access-points
- http://127.0.0.1:5550/5G

...I am new to sphinx, Read the Docs and web development. I will host my website on Read the Docs after that.

So I appreciate if you could explain your suggestions in a way that I can digest

Comment: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-defined-redirects.html By default it provides some options for you. If you want full control, then put a reverse proxy in front.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.Unfortunately I don't know how to do that for now. I would like to find a more beginner friendly approach so that I could implement.